# I'm not able to retrieve value from mongodb even though it exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm running mongo locally. Here I insert the entry into my database and verify it exists

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
> use testing
switched to db testing
> db.vetschool.insert({name: 'My First Cat'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.vetschool.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c051cbd7bd69709fa7d98a"), "name" : "My First Cat" }
```

Here I define my schema and execute the findOne() function which returns a null value. While not shown, I do require mongoose at the top of my document.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
});
var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

Kitten.findOne().exec(function(err, success){
        console.log(success); //returns null
        console.log(err); //returns null
})
```

This is probably too much additional information but here is the output when i start the server and the null value that is output

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead:   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
Listening on port 3000...
Successfully connected to MongoDB
null
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: you're using mongo to insert a document by hand into the `vetschool` collection, then asking Mongoose to look for that document inside the `Kittens` collection.

long answer:  Mongoose automatically determines a collection's name based on the schema name you pass it.  from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html :

`The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database.`

So if you do some things via Mongoose and some things manually, it's up to you to make sure the collection names match.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It looks like I might be missing something else though. I created the Kittens collection, added an entry, restarted mongo and server and still getting null

Comment: Ha ok I figured it out, and your answer definitely helped. You mentioned how collections was determined and then I realized I hadn't specified which database to look into, and was actually creating another database before making my collection. Creating a collection in the default database titled kittens worked.

Just out of curiosity, how would I specify a different database?

Comment: ohh, yes, the database names are different too (`test` vs. `testing`)!  According to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections , you can specify the database name in your connection string.  So instead of `mongodb://localhost/test`, use `mongodb://localhost/foo` for database `foo`.